# How the dependency drop will work during onload with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

There is some data inside a table [image]

When I press the edit button, I can edit all the data for that row.Menu Category and Menu These two data came from Dependent dropdown.

[image]

with this code the dropdown in the menu was supposed to show when the menu categories were selected.

```
   modal.find('.modal-body #menu_category_update').val(menu_item_category_selected);
   modal.find('.modal-body #menu_update').val(menu_item_selected);
```

This code goes through the menu category ID and selects Fastfood Dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change','#menu_category_update',function(){
        $("#menu_update").empty();
        var ddl_menu1 = GetLoadApptUpdate($(this).val());
        $("menu_update").empty();
        $('#menu_update').select2({
            placeholder: "--Select Menu--",
            data: ddl_menu1,
            dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
        });
    });
});

function GetLoadApptUpdate(id) {
    var b = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        url: "/admin/menu/item/entry1/"+id,
        success: function (response) {
            b = response;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            b = { id: 0, text: "No Data" }
        }
    });
    return b;
};
```

`#menu_category_update` The function that is being called with this ID is working properly. But my problem is that when I click on the edit button, a dropdown is selected by default, for which the dependent dropdown is not selected.

Expected answer: [image]

Comment: The issue isn't clear from the screenshots or your description, however I can tell you that using `async: false` is incredibly bad practice and needs to be removed from your code. Use the async pattern correctly by utilising a callback or promise to handle the response from the AJAX request.

Comment: First look at the data in the table then look at the data in the pop-up window then you will understand what has happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$('#menu_category_update').val(menu_item_category_selected);
    modal.find('.modal-body #menu_update').val(menu_item_selected);

    var menu_category_update_val = $("#menu_category_update option:selected").val();
    var menu_update_val = $("#menu_update option:selected").val();
    if (menu_category_update_val !== "") {
        func();
        $('#menu_update').val(menuItemSelected).trigger('change');
    }

function func() {
    $('#menu_category_update').change(function () {
        $("#menu_update").empty();
        var ddl_menu1 = GetLoadApptUpdate1($(this).val());
        $('#menu_update').select2({
            placeholder: "--Select Menu--",
            data: ddl_menu1,
            dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
        });
    }).change();

    function GetLoadApptUpdate1(id) {
        var b = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: true,
            async: false,
            url: "/admin/menu/item/entry1/" + id,
            success: function (response) {
                b = response;
            },
            error: function (response) {
                b = {id: 0, text: "No Data"}
            }
        });
        return b;
    };
}
```